# mysql subquery? My method seams like a cheap way of doing it

Tags: mysql

First question [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccjmK.png)

My first query write a query to list each Course Name and the Average Progress of students in that course. The output should be sorted descending by average progress.

My result was this, which I believe is correct:

```
 SELECT 
     Course.name 'Course Name',
     ROUND(AVG(StudentCourse.progress), 1) 'Average Progress (%)'       
 FROM
      Course
          LEFT JOIN
      StudentCourse ON Course.ID = StudentCourse.CourseID         
 GROUP BY Course.ID                                               
 ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(StudentCourse.progress), 1) DESC;
```

The output is a list of the averages for the courses in Descending order by grade.

The next query is to select the max of the averages, which im not sure how to subquery and my method seems a little cheap  I simply just limited the descending output to 1, which I believe is the improper way.  Please Help!

```
SELECT 
     Course.name 'Course Name',
     ROUND(AVG(StudentCourse.progress), 1) 'Average Progress (%)'       
 FROM
      Course
          LEFT JOIN
      StudentCourse ON Course.ID = StudentCourse.CourseID         
 GROUP BY Course.ID                                               
 ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(StudentCourse.progress), 1) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That's fine, I do it all the time. It works if you only need the overall top. It doesn't work if you need something lie the top student per class or something like that. Or the top 3 students per class. For those, we need more complex solutions, and many have been posted in the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Comment: how would i do it with a subquery? do you know